# Calculating 95% CI for percentages (prevalence).

Tags: chi-squared-test

My sample population includes elderly men and women (age 60-90 years) with information about the prevalence of HBP. I want to make a contingency table showing the distribution of HBP (column variable) across the age groups (60-69, 70-79, 80-90). X2 tests in SPSS, STATA, Rcmdr are able to calculate the percentages(some prefer to say prevalence) of HBP.  however I want to show the 95%CI for those percentages (like on the picture below), which I am failing to figure how. I consulted Dr Google, but no smart solution. (May be question is too dim!)

I really appreciate any insight on this in plain language (without much mathematical expressions).

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As percentages denotes a proportion of a population, you should use the traditional formula for the proportion CI. You can find the formula and an example here: http://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/how-to-determine-the-confidence-interval-for-a-population-proportion/

First, you'll have to transform your data to per-one instead of percent, then you can calculate the CI and transform it back to percentage.

Comment: Thaks for input Alex!

Answer (score 0):

I think Àlex Porcel, gave you already a correct answer. I just want to add how to do it with a software. If you want to do it within R you could use the [binom.test](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/binom.test.html) function with x being the number of people having HBP in the age group, n being the total number of people within the age group and p being the prevalence. It seems you prefer other software like SPSS for example. This mute [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcWcmJSvnf4) seems to explain how to do it in SPSS. However, I don't use SPSS, so I cannot tell.

Comment: You are right bee guy I am illiterate in programming softwares and rely on point and click commands. This is why I use Rcmdr. Thanks for sharing the video (It actually calculates CI for mean, not percentage). I will download the binom package and try the way as described. Also, in case you use Rcmdr or JGR, could you please advise how to do the binom test on that platform.

Comment: The binom.test function is in the stats package that is usually already installed when you install R. I don't know Rcmdr or JGR.